# How to add an item to an Excel menu using VSTO?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

I'm developing an Excel Add-in using VB.NET. On this Add-in, I create a new Ribbon, and inside this Ribbon there will be a Menu of Excel Workbooks and each line of the Menu should have a submenu for the Workbooks' Worksheets (Those file names, paths and sheets are being retrieved from DB).

I'm having problems trying to insert those Workbooks as Menu Items. I created a DAL to retrieve all data that I need and tested , it works, my problem is to add each element of the Workbook list. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
Public Class Ribbon1
    Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim listaWorkbooks As New List(Of Workbook)
        Dim serviceExecuta As New ServiceExecuta

        listaWorkbooks = serviceExecuta.BuscaWorkbooks()

        For Each Workbook In listaWorkbooks

            Menu1.Items.Add(Workbook.getNome)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a button to load the worksheets in to Combo boxes in the Ribbon...
Same way, you can check for workbooks as well.
please refer to below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button19.Click
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim rdi As RibbonDropDownItem
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nm() As String
    For i = 1 To Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Sheets.Count
        ReDim nm(i)
        nm(i) = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Sheets(i).Name
        rdi = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem()
        rdi.Label = nm(i)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(rdi)
    Next i
End Sub
```

May be you can try something like this :

```
        For i = 1 To Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Count
            ReDim nm(i)
            nm(i) = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks(i).Name
            rdi = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem()
            rdi.Label = nm(i)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(rdi)
        Next i
```

Good Luck!